# How to Export JUNIT Test Result as XML in Spring Boot Application for SonarQube Purpose?

Tags: xml, spring, sonarqube, junit4, sonarqube-scan

I already search on Google and Stackoverflow about this Question, and don't have any answer that related to this kind of question.

So the problem is, I have a Project with Spring MVC. I create simple test like this:

```
@Autowired
private UserLogicService logicService;;


@Test
public void helloTrue(){
    //return should be 1
    assertThat(logicService.hello(), is(1)); //test return success
}
@Test
public void helloFalse(){
    //return should be 1
    assertThat(logicService.hello(), is(2)); //test return fail
}
```

And then I need to export it to XML because I read the documentation of SonarQube, [HERE](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project), The tests execution reports have to comply to the JUnit XML format.

I use SonarScanner third party to Scan my Spring Project. So I need to Export my JUnit result as XML and scan it with SonarScanner.

Is there any Setting to Automatically export JUnit Test Result to a folder as XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a build tool like maven or gradle. There you can find plugins which do the trick for you.

[Gradle plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube)

Comment: Ah forgot to mention, I use Maven. I just search and Suddenly found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282767/junit3-and-junit4-xml-reports-with-maven
Thank you for the answer, suddenly enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Execute your tests with JaCoCo or Cobertura, then provide the paths to the coverage reports with either `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` or `sonar.cobertura.reportPath` as described [in the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project).

You only need to translate to an XML format if your test engine doesn't provide a format that the language analyzer already understands.